# Подключение части файла (require)

Tags: php, require

Как с помощью `require` подключить не весь файл, а только его часть? Например:
`index.php:`

```
$text = 'Привет';
echo $text;
$day = 21;
echo $day;
```

`second.php:`

```
require 'index.php';
```

Как подключать, допустим, только `$text = 'Привет';` и `echo $text;`?

Comment: никак, это невозможно. оформите нужный код в функцию/метод.

Comment: Ну, можно поизвращаться: читать строки файла и загонять их в `eval()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень странный подход и делать так не нужно.

Но если очень хочется делать именно так, то:

1. Перед `require` объявляете переменную, например, `$codePart = "part_1"`;
2. Файл `index.php` форматируете следующим образом:

---

```
if (!empty($codePart)) {
    switch ($codePart) {
        case 'part_1':
            $text = 'Привет';
            echo $text;
            break;
        case 'part_2':
            $day = 21;
            echo $day;
            break;
    }
}
```

В `second.php` у Вас будет что-то вроде:

```
$codePart = 'part_1';
require 'index.php';
```

По факту, файл будет включен весь, но выведется только выбранная часть. Подход этот плохой и тупиковый.

Гораздо лучше (хотя тоже не оптимально), вынести нужные Вам блоки в отдельные функции, а потом просто вызывать их, где нужно.

---

```
index.php:

<?php

function partOne() {
    echo 'Привет';
}

function partTwo() {
    echo 21;
}

second.php:

<?php

include('index.php');

partOne(); //выводится "Привет"
partTwo(); //выводится 21
```

---

Так у Вас файл будет включен ровно один раз, а блоки можно выводить, где нужно.

А еще лучше почитать про шаблонизаторы.

Answer (score 0):

В php, include/require подключает и исполняет файл. Вы не сможете импортировать часть файла, как например это сделано в Python или Java.
По сути include/require "вставляет" содержимое файла вместо своего вызова, даже если он будет в теле функции, кроме так называемых "магических" констант тип **FILE** или **DIR** которые обрабатываются интерпретатором php до подключения.